# Request private certificate is disabled: how come?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to generate a private certificate through the AWS certificate manager but it seems I can only request a public one.
Is there any kind of permission needed to do so? My account should have full access to everything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your account should not) AWS ACM provides private certificates only from Private certificate authority what u can create. And it costs [a lot](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/private-certificate-authority/).

AWS ACM integrates with a lot of AWS services like Cloudfront, API Gateway, ALB and others and u can attach those certificates to them like an alias. Private certificated exist only for manual configuration your VM's or containers